# How to edit data on POST request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `patientStatus()` function and onClick it will set the `p.status` to be the id of the clicked button & at the same time it creates a timestamp saved as value of `p.timestamp`. This `patient's data` from the `patients array` is sent on a post request `('/observation/record')` to save in the database.

Now, if I want to edit the saved record, I need the timestamp that was taken previously and passed as `replace: lastTimestamp` to the same post endpoint. 
`Edit behavior` - When I click on the button the first time it should just sent data on the post with the timestamp but if I click on the again or on an another button then that's an edit and it is then where I need to send another post request with the lastTimeStamp and replace it with the new one.

I can do the initial post and save the data with the timestamp, but I don't exactly know how to execute the code/logic for editing. The design doesn't have an edit button either. Whenever the the patienStatus is called onClick, the data is sent on a post.

```
patientStatus = (e, patient) => {
 const { id } = e.target;

 this.setState({

     patients: 
     this.state.patients.map(p => {

         if (p.id === patient.id) {
             const timestamp = Date.now(); //create a timestamp

             return { ...p, status: id, timestamp };
         }
         return p;
     }),

 }, () => {
     this.postObservationRecord(patient); 
 });
}
```

```
postObservationRecord(patient) {
    this.state.patients.map(p  => {

        if ((p.id === patient.id ) && (p.timestamp)) {

            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/observation/record',
                data: {
                    room: p.room,
                    patient: p.id,
                    timestamp: p.timestamp,
                    presentation: p.status,
                }
            })
                .then(res => {
                    if(res.status === 200 && res.statusText === 'OK') {                       
                        console.log('request sent');
                    }else {
                        console.log('request failed');
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => { throw new Error(err); });
        }
    });
}
```

```
<div>
    <Button id="Awake" onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient,)}> Awake </Button>
    <Button id="Asleep" onClick={(e) => patientStatus(e, patient)}>Asleep</Button>
</div>
```

```
this.state = {
       patients: [
                  { room: "1", name: 'John', timestamp: ‘’ , status: ''},
                  { room: "2", name: 'Shawn', timestamp: ‘’, status: ''},
                 ]
              }
```

Comment: Add a new field `lastTimeStamp` to state which maintains the previous value of the current `timeStamp`

Answer (score 2):

Add a new field `lastTimeStamp` to state which maintains the previous value of the current timeStamp and send it along the body of Axios but this is bad system design.

I think you are trying to access a row using its timestamp. Instead, I would have done it in the following way:

### At the time of post request:

#### Client side:

The client sends data with fields containing `room, name and status`.

#### Server side:

Server receives fields `room, name and status`. The server upon receiving the request generates a time-stamp and primary-key and stores into the database with fields `primary-key, room, name, status and timestamp`.Send the response containing all fields to the client.

### At the time of edit(i.e PUT) request:

#### Client side:

The client sends data with fields containing `new-room, new-name, new-status and primary-key`(received in the post response)

#### Server side:

Server recives `new-room, new-name, new-status and primary-key`. The server upon receiving the request identifies which table row to update using `primary-key`. It then updates the database table with fields `new-room, new-name, and new-status`

Comment: when I click on the button the first time it should just sent data on the post with the timestamp but if I click on the another button again then that's an edit and it is then I need to send another post request with the lastTimeStamp and replace it with the new one which I don't know how to put in on code? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I guess you have a bad database design then. Instead, you can do one thing. Whenever you post data on the server-side, generate timestamp there and not on the client-side. Next time if you wanna update that record update it using the primary key, not the timestamp. After updating the record you can set the new timestamp on the server itself.